# How to clone clarifai-android-sdk using "git lfs"?

Tags: android, git, github, git-lfs, clarifai

I want to create an object detection application using clarifai android library found in the following link:

[**clarifai android**](https://github.com/Clarifai/docs/blob/master/android.md?fbclid=IwAR114v4A8Njz_ZVmNu6lCckN972sisKAsc1TeyZyl9Fy5BUeBCAcR8fs-Fk)

The documentation is very clear but the problem is in cloning the **clarifai-android-sdk** using **git-lfs**

and this what is mentioned in the documentation:

> **1) Git LFS**
>
> Before doing anything else, please make sure you have Git-LFS
> installed on your system. The binary contained in the framework is
> managed by GitHub using git-lfs.
>
> If you don't have it installed yet, you can find details at:
> https://git-lfs.github.com. IF YOU DON'T HAVE GIT-LFS INSTALLED, THE
> SDK WILL NOT WORK.
>
> **2) Verifying the SDK**
>
> After setting up Git LFS, please ensure that the SDK
> cloned correctly, by checking the size of the *.aar. **If the size is
> less than ~120MB, then you will need to re-pull master now that Git
> LFS is set up.**
>
> If you downloaded a ZIP of the project via the "Clone or download"
> button, the SDK will be cloned incorrectly. Either clone the repo with
> git, or download the *.aar file specifically by clicking on the file
> through GitHub, and clicking the "Download" button.

if it is not clear this is a [link of the full clarifai-android-sdk documentation](https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-android-sdk)

I have already installed **git-lfs** but when I try to clone the repository of  **clarifai-android-sdk** the size of **'.aar'** file is 100 megabyte not as mentioned previously that:

> **if the  '*.aar' file is less than 120 megabyte then you will need to**
> **re-pull master now that Git LFS is set up.**

so generally: I need to know what should I do to solve this problem ?
and specifically what  is the meaning of **re-pull master now that Git LFS is set up.**

Comment: Hi Amr, was the answer below helpful (if so please mark it so others can find more easily).  Otherwise are you still having the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that doing a `git pull` would solve that (yeah its unusual to do it right after a `git clone` but that seems to be what it is saying.